# Need to print 0 in front while printing the time in oracl plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to print the time of an operation taken by insert or update in a plsql block .So right now it gives the output as `.23` secs I need to have output as `0.23` secs. If its greater than 0 then its coming fine.

Only to handle in case when its less than 1 sec and append 0 before decimal.

I am doing like this

```
(DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start_time) / 100 secs
```

l_start_time is taken at the star of operation -

```
l_start_time := dbms_utility.get_time;
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply `TO_CHAR` function with desired format mask to the result. For example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_start_time number := dbms_utility.get_time;
  3    l_duration   number;
  4    l_cnt number;
  5  begin
  6    select count(*) into l_cnt from user_objects;
  7    l_duration := (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start_time) / 100;
  8    dbms_output.put_line(l_duration);                            --> short, unformatted
  9    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_duration, '999G990D00'));     --> short, formatted
 10
 11    --
 12
 13    select count(*) into l_cnt from all_objects;
 14    l_duration := (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start_time) / 100;
 15    dbms_output.put_line(l_duration);                            --> long, unformatted
 16    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_duration, '999G990D00'));     --> long, formatted
 17  end;
 18  /
,04             --> short, unformatted
0,04            --> short, formatted - that's what you'd want to see
5,89
5,89

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick response so it will  work for any duration whether less than 0 or greater than 0 ?

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, that's right; I suggested one format mask, you can change it if you want. See documentation for more info.

Answer (score 1):

While using
to_char(l_duration, '999G990D00') it will work for any duration whether less than 0 or greater than 0 it's all depend on the format mask.